# distributed cache with hazelcast

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast, distributed-cache

I want to check the distributed caching functionality using hazelcast with hibernate. Hazelcast has provided the integration with hibernate for second level cache. How can we check the hazelcast distributed cache functionality with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a small demo application and add hibernate integration to it. Have I missed the point of the question?

Comment: I have done the small demo application integrating the hibernate second level cache with hazelcast. I want to test the distributed cache functionality. so I ran the application 2 times, so that 1st time queried, should be cached from the 2nd test. But it was not happening.i am using the following configurations. I am using com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory

Comment: If I am running the sample application 2 times, every time one sessionfactory object get created.So I feel secondlevel cache will bind to sessiofactory, the queries in one sessionfactory will not get accessed by another session factory query objects.